# Does the 3-3 invasion work with 3 stones already placed?

Tags: go, invasion

With the three black stones placed, I did the [3-3](http://senseis.xmp.net/?AllAbout33PointInvasion) invasion.

```
$$Wm1
$$ ----------
$$ ........|
$$ ...X....|
$$ ...X.1..|
$$ ....X...|
$$ ........|
```

I tried tried to force a [KO](http://senseis.xmp.net/?Ko) and did get 2 moves elsewhere, but I would rather have lived.

```
$$Wm1
$$ ----------
$$ ........|
$$ ...X..5.|
$$ ...X.O.7|
$$ ....X236|
$$ ......4.|
```

Does 3-3 invasion work here?

Answer (score 4):

Liam showed a good way to kill the invasion already, but you can be even more mean and play 2 at 4:

```
$$Wm1
$$ ----------
$$ ........|
$$ ...X....|
$$ ...X.1..|
$$ ....X...|
$$ ......2.|
```

If white then plays 3, you just draw back instead of playing below 1, and you avoid a cut at 4:

```
$$Wm1
$$ ----------
$$ .....c..|
$$ ...Xb.a.|
$$ ...X.1..|
$$ ....X.3.|
$$ .....42.|
```

Then, a, b and c are miai to kill.

The cut would not usually be dangerous, but it at least allows white to get 1 or 2 outside sente moves in the area, which is more than she should get - the original invasion at 3-3 was way too deep (the deepest possible would be white 1 at 2 in the above diagram, but that is a bit advanced, don't worry about it too much).

White may try to be sneaky and return to the variation with the cut present like this:

```
$$Wm1
$$ ----------
$$ ........|
$$ ...X....|
$$ ...X.1..|
$$ ....X...|
$$ .....32.|
```

In that case, you can easily play at 6 instead of a to gain more and avoid white's sente atari at 6. The white inside group is still dead as per what we saw above.

```
$$Wm1
$$ ----------
$$ ........|
$$ ...X....|
$$ ...X.1a.|
$$ ....X45.|
$$ .....32.|
$$ ......6.|
```

Answer (score 1):

Black 6 should be at white 7. After this white dies uncondittionally.

https://online-go.com/demo/66482